# Threads preventing program termination

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on javafx application which doesn't terminate on `Platform.exit()`. By trial and error I've tapered cause to one method which starts two background tasks. But both tasks(futures) cancelled and are `isDone` before `exit` called.

I've had pretty much same code working fine with swing. So I wonder if it's javafx 'thing' or I'm just stupid.

I've googled extensively but not found anything on general teqniques for tracking down 'undying' threads.

Comment: How are you creating the threads which are running the tasks?

Comment: According to the documentation, if there are no more deamon threads, the JVM will exit. Are you sure you are not creating any new threads?

Comment: no more *non-*daemon threads ;)

Comment: I'm creating futures via `ExecutorService::submit` and `ScheduledExecutorService::sceduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: @user2418306 You need to call ExecutorService::shutdown at some stage if you want your application to exit, to to change the TreadFactory of the executor to create daemon threads...

Comment: The best place to call `shutdown` on the `ExecutorService` is probably in the `Application`'s [`stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--) method. It's hard to give a specific answer to this question without some code being posted.

Comment: @npinti it is exaclty the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm creating futures via ExecutorService::submit andScheduledExecutorService::sceduleAtFixedRate

Threads created by default `ThreadFactory` are NON DEAMON, so the application will run until `shutdown` will be called. To workaround this, implement your tasks to be "interruptable" and call `shutdownNow()` on the executor OR provide custom `ThreadFactory` that will create deamon threads with `Thread.setDeamon(true)`. This way, executor threads will terminate upon termination of the main application thread.